# MagePlaza Social Logins Facebook Error: Ooophs, we got an error: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id

Tags: magento2, login, facebook

For some reason when I try to use the MagePlaza Social Login extension, Facebook login throws this error:

```
Ooophs, we got an error: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.
```

I added the correct app id and secret to the config in the admin section.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the base_facebook.php in method getAccessTokenFromCode() change this:

```
$response_params = array();
parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);
```

to this:

```
$response_params = json_decode($access_token_response, true);
```

Mageplaza has been fixed that issue, see on Github https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-social-login/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

In the Facebook, Developer page add you site URL to the access list.

Comment: I am using localhost. Site URL is "http://localhost:8000/". App domain is "localhost". Could there be a problem there?

Comment: You can try add localhost into list. Normally I would use vhost to have URL like: somedomain.myname for my local project. Basically Facebook filter the request address with the list, so localhost maybe is acceptable.