# social login magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-social

I installed mageplaza social login but i got those error when trying to connect [image]

[image]

Comment: it would be useful if you translate the error.

Comment: Check @nedi response https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166630/mageplaza-social-logins-facebook-error-ooophs-we-got-an-error-authentication , maybe you have the same error.

Comment: @Bare feet  can you please tell me how the error is usufull and thanks for your replay brother

Comment: Just for fun :D Did you check te Yigen Guxholi link?

Comment: ok :) but the error still there any suggestion please

Comment: i did not find this base_facebook.php  !!!??